# Styling Progress Bar in WPF with XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I want to change Heigth of my progress bar but I can't, property "height" doesn't work.

I have this:

[image]

And I need like this:

[image]

My XAML code is:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="pgsConnectionQuality" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
             VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100" Margin="276,0,198,0"  Width="150" 
             Value="{Binding ConnectionQuality}"/>
```

How can I do? Thanks!

Comment: Why dont you use the style mechanism in WPF? r alternatively use a control template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height property works fine for me. Your first pic doesn't look like a standard progress bar. Are you sure you don't have a style setting it somewhere?

Comment: I am using materialDesing